# Jenkins declarative pipeline: How to fingerprint a file without archiving it?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, fingerprinting

I have a Jenkins declarative pipeline job that has the end result of creating some very large output files ( >  2 GB in size ).  **I don't want to archive these files in Jenkins as artifacts.**

However, I would like to fingerprint these large files so that I can associate them with other builds.

How can I do this, preferably in the post action of the pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your pipeline script add: `fingerprint 'module/dist/**/*.zip'`

Where `'module/dist/**/*.zip'` are the files you wish to fingerprint [using Ant's FileSet](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html)

In console log you should see:

```
Recording fingerprints
[Pipeline] ...
```

While users have mentioned in the [Jenkins documentation](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Fingerprint) that files also need to be **archived** for the build not to fail, this work for me on Jenkins ver. 2.180.

Comment: Worked perfectly in the post / always section, thank you!